# Vim escaping non-ascii value for pasting

Tags: vim, copy-paste

I am trying to paste a string from a register in VIM which contains non-ASCII characters such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>, how can I paste this string into a file, but escape the non-ASCII characters automatically?

Essentially, what I am trying to achieve is recording a macro which has some (non-ascii) characters, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> which vim will show as ^W.  I want to be able to take the macro (by examining the registers and taking the macro string (i.e @a=^W)) and copying it into a .vimrc file as a key-map, so that when I press the key it will run that macro.

I want to do this automatically (or as fast as possible) without having to change ^W into <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> in the .vimrc file, or wherever I paste it too.

Comment: Duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103567/vim-paste-string-with-non-ascii-characters; please don't post in parallel to multiple Stack Exchange sites!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *control sequences* **are within the ASCII range** (`^W` is code point 23) but they are so-called *unprintable* characters. You can paste those verbatim into your `~/.vimrc` file (as long as you use Vim registers, and not terminal selection and paste); **no escaping is needed**. (There may only be problems with `^J` and `^M`, depending on the file format of your `~/.vimrc`.)

That said, here is a simple substitution that will escape those control sequences:

```
:echo substitute("example: \<C-A>\<C-Z>", '[\x00-\x1f]', '\="<C-" . nr2char(char2nr(submatch(0)) + 64) . ">"', 'g')
```